# How to get the index of the clicked array element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a array list of span elements dynamically created. I want to get the index of the clicked span element.

```
boundItemClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target) //results <span>some label</span>
}
render() {
    var data=[];
    data.push (<div>
        <span>{textLabel} onClick={this.boundItemClick.bind(this)}</span>
        </div>
}
```

However I'm unable to get the index this way, what is the best way to get the index of a clicked array element?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've added a few tags, let me know if they were inappropriate. It does not appear to be standard javascript, and instead some mix of react and jsx.

Comment: The parentheses are unbalanced.

Comment: Is this redux, react, ...? Please tag your question with the templating framework you are using.

Comment: yes forgot to include the tags, it includes react jsx templating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the current length of the data array as index to your function:

```
boundItemClick(idx, e) { // add idx as argument
    console.log(idx);
}
render() {
    var data=[];
    data.push (<div>
        <span>{textLabel} onClick={this.boundItemClick.bind(this, data.length)}</span>
        </div> );
}
```

Comment: `this` is the `span` on which the click handler was bound, and thus its parent is the `div` of which it is a child.

Comment: I'm getting undefined on "this. parentElement".

Comment: Could you verify that `this` is the span element?

Comment: i have added an snippet of the data array as image above.

Comment: also added an image of "this", nope does not include the span element, includes the wrapped component.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer to pass the index to the handler instead of the data array.

Answer (score 0):

**`Pure JS`** solution.

**Note**: It counts from 1, but if you want you can adjust it to count indexes from 0.

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
[...spans].forEach((v,i) => v.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(i+1);
}));
```

```html
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
```

**`jQuery`** solution.

```js
$('span').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the elements assigning a click event listener to each element and use a lambda to cache and pass the index to the custom handler function.

```js
// Initialize our dynamically created elements array
const elements = [];

// Simulate the creation of elements dynamically
const mkButton = text => Object.assign(document.createElement('button'),  { textContent: text })
for(var i = 10; i-- > 0;) elements.push(document.body.appendChild(mkButton('click')));

// Custom handler function
const handler = index => console.log(index);

// Assign the listener with the cached index to each element
elements.forEach((e, i) => e.addEventListener('click', event => handler(i), false));
```